# How to execute a simple command line with CreateProcess?

Tags: c++, winapi, command-line

I'd like to execute a simple command line but without to make a window appear. Therefore I can't use System and have to use CreateProcess as far as I know.
So I have the following code for example:

```
//.../

CreateProcess(NULL,input,NULL,NULL,false,NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS | 
 CREATE_NO_WINDOW,NULL,NULL,&startInf,&procInf);//)

//.../
```

If input is a line like *"ping www.google.com -n 2"* it seems to work.
What I need is the deletion-function though.
Therefore I tried a lot of variations like:

```
input = "rd /S /Q \"D:\\ALEX_DATEN\\PC\\C++\\bla\"";
```

and

```
  input = "rd /S /Q \"D:/DATEN/PC/C++/bla\"";
```

But nothing happens and the function returns failure :/
If I write it as a .bat file (without using the "\" escaping chars) the deleting works perfectly!

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

P.s. no, I'm not writing a destructive virus.. if that would have been my target, I would have definitely have found simpler ways...

Comment: Uhm, I don't really see why to use that. As far as I udnerstand here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx it wants to execute a file but I just need to execute a string...

Comment: cppguy is right, imo; ShellExecute is designed for running command lines, whereas CreateProcess is designed for running a specific executable file.  So, as I see it, some of your options are 1) Use ShellExecute, 2) Create a dummy executable that wraps ShellExecute (or something like that) and run the dummy via CreateProcess, or 3) see if you can directly execute the binary that implements the rd command.  IMO, ShellExecute is the path of least resistance.

Comment: `rd` is a command built into the shell, so you can't execute it (at least directly) with `CreateProcess`. To do it, you'd need to execute `cmd.exe` as the executable, and have it execute your `rd /S ...`.

Comment: Oh okey o-o Interesting. So does that means that I can place as the argument lpFile, simply the command line?

Comment: Jerry Coffin: ahhh.. okey, that makes sense too!

Comment: The system() function would be simpler.

Comment: Carey Gregory, yes but it dispalys a window what I don't want!
And I don't manage to make ShellExecute working.. =/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some system command like `rd`, `del` and ... are not actual executable Images (e.g. .exe Files), so you can't execute/run them using `CreateProcess` they are built-in commands that known to `cmd`(command interpreter of windows) so you should create `cmd` and pass your command to it:

```
wchar_t cmd[ MAX_PATH ];
size_t nSize = _countof(cmd);
_wgetenv_s( &nSize, cmd, L"COMSPEC" );
BOOL b = CreateProcessW( cmd, input, NULL, NULL, FALSE,
    NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS | CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &startInf, &procInf );
```

Note: Please see arguments of `cmd`, you have to use `/C` to pass your command. So your command is as follow:

```
wchar_t input[] = L"some command";
wchar_t cmd[MAX_PATH] ;
// initialize cmd
wchar_t cmdline[ MAX_PATH + 50 ];
swprintf_s( cmdline, L"%s /c %s", cmd, input );
STARTUPINFOW startInf;
memset( &startInf, 0, sizeof startInf );
startInf.cb = sizeof(startInf);
// If you want to redirect result of command, set startInf.hStdOutput to a file
// or pipe handle that you can read it, otherwise we are done!
PROCESS_INFORMATION procInf;
memset( &procInf, 0, sizeof procInf );
BOOL b = CreateProcessW( NULL, cmdline, NULL, NULL, FALSE,
    NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS | CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &startInf, &procInf );
DWORD dwErr = 0;
if( b ) {
    // Wait till cmd do its job
    WaitForSingleObject( procInf.hProcess, INFINITE );
    // Check whether our command succeeded?
    GetExitCodeProcess( procInfo.hProcess, &dwErr );
    // Avoid memory leak by closing process handle
    CloseHandle( procInfo.hProcess );
} else {
    dwErr = GetLastError();
}
if( dwErr ) {
    // deal with error here
}
```

Comment: Ohh okey o: I will try that. Uses functions I haven't encountered yet, but thanks!

Comment: @ChitianK thanks for your edit, I'm not a native English speaker. So thanks for your help

Comment: Uhm, what do I have to include to have the fucntion GetProcessExitCode? It doiesn't seem to find it.
And how do I initialize startInf? LPSTARTUPINFOW startInf; Doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry I edit my answer, correct function is `GetExitCodeProcess`!!

Comment: What do you want from `startInf`? it will be set to zero, `startInf.cb = sizeof startInf` and if you want the result of operation then set `hStdOutput` to a file that you read later, or even set it to a pipe that created in your program and then receive result of execution through the pipe and if you don't need the output, just ignore it!

Comment: NO, how do I initialize that structure? It's not in your code and LPSTARTUPINFOW startInf; doesn't work.

Comment: `LPSTARTUPINFOW` is a typedef for `STARTUPINFOW*` so you can't use it like that, take a look at my edited answer

Comment: Thank you very much!! 
Your posted code confused me more though, I already had a working system to use the CreateProcess Function. What was needed was to add "cmd.exe /c" infront of the rest of the line.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, `rd` cannot be executed with `CreateProcess()` directly, you have to execute `cmd.exe` with `/C rd ...` as its command-line parameter.  Rather than using `CreateProcess()` like this, you should use `SHFileOperation()` instead:

```
SHFILEOPSTRUCT FileOp = {0};
FilOp.wFunc = FO_DELETE;
FileOp.pFrom = "D:\\ALEX_DATEN\\PC\\C++\\bla\0"; 
FileOp.fFlags = FOF_SILENT | FOF_NOCONFIRMATION | FOF_NOERRORUI.

int ErrorCode = SHFileOperation(&FileOp);
if (ErrorCode == 0)
{
    if (FileOp.fAnyOperationsAborted)
        // not everything was deleted
    else
        // delete was successful
}
else
{
    // delete failed
    // note that ErrorCode might not be a Win32 error code,
    // so check the SHFileOperation() documentation for
    // possible alternatives
}
```

Comment: Ahh thank you as well, but I wanted to make a form which can execute every sort of command line, sorry!